# How to add a dependency of external maven project to current project?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have my own maven project:

```
/path/to/my_project/
                    pom.xml
                    /src/main/java/com/my/MyProject.java
```

`MyProject.java` contains a dependency to external class:

```
package com.my;

import com.other.ExternalClass;
class MyProject {
    ExternalClass d;
}
```

External class is located in another maven project:

```
/path/to/another_project/
                         pom.xml
                         /src/main/java/com/other/ExternalClass.java
```

How to specify dependency such that `mvn install` command executed on my project would not throw error `package com.other does not exist`

Comment: You have to add a `<dependency>` to that project into your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `mvn install` the project `another_project`

You add a `<dependency>` entry with the correct coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) of `another_project`  to the `pom.xml` of `my_project`.

Then you `mvn install` the project `my_project`.